# MDX Hierarchy Dimension to Column

Tags: sql-server, mdx, mdx-query

I have a cube having a dimension using hierarchy. This is the example of pivot cube from Excel using pivot level

[image]

This data are attached as one hierarchy drill down from Excel pivot

[image]

When I translated it to MDX query:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {[VALUE] } ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { 
{[PROFITLEVEL].[Profit Center].&[Level02],[Profit Center].&[Level03],[Profit Center].&[Level04],[Profit Center].&[Level05]}

} 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
 
 FROM  [CUBE])
```

I can't create as a picture from Excel pivot, which is data translated to each column (Level 2, 3, 4, 5)

This is result from the query

[image]

The data becomes duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

The depth you are going to I think means that each set of members contains an All member. You need to go a bit further down in each hierarchy e.g.

```
[PROFITLEVEL].[Profit Center].&[Level02].&[Level02]
```